# Why I am not getting "success" with this program?

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have written the following program with the hope of getting success. But I could never get it.

```
my $fileName = 'myfile.txt';
print $fileName,"\n";

if (open MYFILE, "<", $fileName) {
    my $Data;
    {
        local $/ = undef;
        $Data = <MYFILE>;
    }
    my @values = split('\n', $Data);
    chomp(@values);

    if($values[2] eq '9999999999')  {
        print "Success"."\n";
    }

}
```

The content of myfile.txt is

```
160002
something
9999999999
700021
```

Comment: When reading from a file line-by-line, does perl strip the trailing newline?

Comment: Yes, the chomp seems redundent

Comment: remove chomp(@values) and add $cnt=0;  foreach (@values ) { print "$cnt   $_\n";$cnt++}

Comment: Code works for me as is... Since your `print "Success";` line doesn't include a newline, the message may be getting trashed by your prompt...

Comment: @michael did that. But what was the point ? It's still not success. I am able to print the contents of the file line by line.

Comment: @twalberg I tried putting "\n" at the end. Still the same.

Comment: This community is amazing. I tried yesterday for around 5 hours to get past this, but could not. While I get answers almost every-time I come here, It also occurs to me how much more I need to learn. Kudos to you guys out there who keep lending their helping hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting by `\s*[\r\n]+`

```
my $fileName = 'myfile.txt';
print $fileName,"\n";

if (open MYFILE, "<", $fileName) {
    my $Data;
    {
        local $/ = undef;
        $Data = <MYFILE>;
    }
    my @values = split(/\s*[\r\n]+/, $Data);

    if($values[2] eq '9999999999')  {
        print "Success";
    }

}
```

Comment: if you're on linux post `hd myfile.txt`

Comment: i would like to write a blog post about it.

Comment: `/\s*[\r\n]+/` match CR/LF, optional trailing spaces.

Comment: file name: 160001.txt
mime type: 

0000-0010:  31 36 30 30-30 32 0d 0a-73 6f 6d 65-74 68 69 6e  160002.. somethin
0000-0020:  67 0d 0a 39-39 39 39 39-39 39 39 39-39 0d 0a 37  g..99999 99999..7
0000-0027:  30 30 30 32-31 0d 0a                             00021..

Comment: So why was I able to split the line using newline character ?

Comment: split was successful. But $values[2] was '9999999999\r', not '9999999999'.

Comment: lines are terminated with CR/LF as @falsetru pointed out, and not by LF

Answer (score 1):

If `myfile.txt` contain carriage return (CR, \r), it will not work as expected.
Another possible cause is trailing spaces before linefeed (LF, \n).

Comment: I am using newline character to split the contents. Which I am able to do and print perfectly. It means it's not \r at the end. There are no trailing spaces either.

Comment: bubble : how about if($values[2] =~ /9999999999/)  {
        print "Success";
    }

Comment: @michael, that could match 889999999999. `/^9999999999\s*/` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read an entire file into an array to check one line. Open the file, skip the lines you don't care about, then play with the line you do care about. When you've done what you need to do, stop reading the file. This way, only one line is ever in memory:

```
my $fileName = 'myfile.txt';
open MYFILE, "<", $fileName or die "$filename: $!";

while( <MYFILE> ) {
    next if $. < 3;  # $. is the line number
    last if $. > 3;

    chomp;
    print "Success\n" if $_ eq '9999999999';
    }

close MYFILE;
```

Comment: I actually need other data as well! I cut short my question to the specific difficulty.

Comment: It's easy to modify this to do different things for different line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $fileName = 'myfile.txt';
open MYFILE, "<", $fileName || die "$fileName: $!";

while( $rec = <MYFILE> ) {
   for ($rec) { chomp; s/\r//; s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; } #Remove line-feed and space characters
   $cnt++;  
   if ( $rec =~ /^9+$/ ) { print "Success\n"; last; }  #if record matches "9"s only 
                                                       #print "Success" and live the loop  
}

close MYFILE;

#Or you can write: if ($cnt==3 and $rec =~ /^9{10}$/) { print "Success\n"; last; } 
#If record 3 matches ten "9"s print "Success" and live the loop.
```